# Sending email to outlook domain

Tags: marketing-cloud

We can send email to gmail in SFMC test instance but not to outlook. Is that something that needs to be enabled at salesforce end?

Comment: You can select subscribers with certain domain names in a few different ways.  Either through an SQL query, or just hand selecting an @gmail.com address.  However, outlook is a domain, but also a email client.  You cannot control what client an end user is actually using.  Please clarify your question further.

Comment: This sounds like a deliverability problem and not an issue from SFMC. Your best bet would be to whitelist your from emailaddress and your sending IP on both your Receiving Server (for Outlook, it is usually hosted on Exchange) and your Outlook Client to prevent it from being blocked or sent to spam folder.

Answer (score 3):

Sending emails from a new SFMC instance, especially if you have been assigned a private IP address, will lead to some emails not coming through to the recipients since you haven't established an adequate sender reputation. Especially Microsoft (Outlook.com, Hotmail.com, Live.com) tends to be quite agressive, when it comes to filtering out email traffic from new senders. Check the spam folder in the receiving end, and follow best practice for IP warmup before going live.

Lukas